# Should I put a comma after etc.?

Tags: commas, etc

Many people use the phrase ***etc.*** in their writing. However, I have never come across an example of using a comma after it.

So, is it

> Almost everybody uses Wi-Fi in their daily lives – be it gaming, emails, searching, etc. for it is their hobby.

OR

> Almost everybody uses Wi-Fi in their daily lives – be it gaming, emails, searching, etc.***,*** for it is their hobby.

?

Or perhaps I should use

> Almost everybody uses Wi-Fi in their daily lives - be it gaming, emails, searching, ***etc,*** for it is their hobby

Comment: Because all of these points have been covered before on ELU. Why are you encouraging duplication?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally one does not put a comma after *etc.*:

> Books, pens, paper, etc. were strewn all over the room.

However, in your sentence, a comma is needed. This is not because of the *etc.* but because *be it gaming, emails, searching, etc.* is in **apposition** to *their daily lives*. An [appositive](http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/f/faqappositive.htm) is a noun, noun phrase, or series of nouns that are provided as an explanatory equivalent to another noun or noun phrase in the sentence. In this case, *be it gaming, emails,* etc. provides additional details about *their daily lives*.

The appositive in this case is **non-restrictive**, i.e., leaving it off will not alter or make unclear the meaning of the sentence. Consider the following examples:

> My sister Joanna lives in Melbourne.
>   My sister, Joanna, lives in Melbourne.

In both cases, *Joanna* is an appositive. However, in the first sentence, it is **restrictive**. The meaning is that I have more than one sister and I'm talking only about this one specific sister; she is the only one of my sisters who lives in Melbourne. Any other sisters I have live elsewhere. In the second sentence, the appositive is non-restrictive, i.e., I'm not restricting the meaning of the sentence to just one of my sisters. I'm saying that I have only one sister, and she lives in Melbourne.

Non-restrictive appositives need to be set off from the rest of the sentence in some way, typically with commas; em-dashes work as well. In your sentence, the appositive is non-restrictive: you're not specifying only *parts* of *their daily life*, you're saying people need wireless *in their daily life taken as a whole*. So you need to put in the comma after *etc.*

As a further example:

> The tools of a writer's trade, i.e., books, pens, paper, etc., were evident on her desk.

Do you see the difference?

That said, your sentence itself is very awkward and sounds unidiomatic:

- Generally, appositives should use parallel punctuation. If you start off with an em-dash, end it with another. Starting with a dash and ending with a comma is inelegant.
- The antecedent of the second *it* is unclear: *wifi*? *their daily lives*? *gaming, emails, searching*? With the exception of *gaming*, none of these qualifies as a hobby, and *gaming* is not an independent subject in the sentence.
- *their daily lives—be it gaming,* etc. is odd. Perhaps you mean *whether for gaming,* etc. *Gaming, emails, searching* is not coextensive with either *daily lives* or *wifi* and makes an odd complement to either.

So the sentence is in need of some rewriting.

Comment: 'be it gaming ...' is not an appositive, though it is an explanatory / enlarging parenthetical. In an appositive construction, either variant may be omitted without losing grammaticality (Mr Major – the Prime Minister – did not take this view.) // I've down-voted as you don't seem to respect the need to avoid duplication.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How would you characterize it, then? By definition, an appositive is an *explanatory, enlarging parenthetical*. Furthermore, the part of the sentence from *be it* through *etc.* can be left out without affecting the grammar of this sentence.

Comment: As I said, the syntactic constraint applies. See [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appositive). CGEL likewise states: '[T]he appositive NP can be substituted for the whole supplementation ...' Thus 'A surprise present, a bouquet of roses, was delivered to my door' may grammatically drop either the original or the appositive NP. However, with 'Almost everybody uses something that uses Wi-Fi – be it gaming, emails, searching, etc – ...' it is incorrect to drop the 'something that uses Wi-Fi. The 'be it' destroys apposition. This is a different class of parenthetical.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Ah good point. I'll edit.

Comment: Why? All this has been covered here before.